# NodeJS crash after a few thousand writes to MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am using a NodeJS server to write data to a MongoDB database. It runs well for a **few thousand writes**. Then it randomly crashes with the following
[error messege](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSCzo.jpg).

It says db is undefined, I've clearly [defined it like here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6oax.jpg).

I'm confused why the definition of "db" suddenly become removed after a while. I want to use this server for at least one hour before crashing. Can someone point what I'm doing wrong?

Extra notes :

1. I'm using `var app = express()` to create an express app and `app.post("/saveData", function(req, res)` function handles HTTP post request as usual.
2. Express is listening to port 90 using `app.listen(90,function()`
3. I'm using bodyParser to handle JSON data
4. NodeJS server and MongoDB database is hosted locally.
5. I'm using `updateOne` to push data to an existing document using the following code.

```
dbObject.updateOne(
                {name: "AKILA"}, 
                {'$push': {Temperature: temp}},
                function (err) {
                                if (err) {res.send("DB Error");}
                                else{res.send("Data Sent");}
                                }
                   );
```

Comment: How do you manage db connections? Do you close the connection each time?

Comment: Hi Akila Uyanwarra, Can you include the text of the errors and code instead of images so the info in the question is searchable. Also the code the error references, line 48 of server.js

Comment: You're likely getting an error and NOT checking that error and then when you blow through that stop sign, you get the `undefined` error you see.  For example, this code right here in your image https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6oax.jpg does not check for an error on the `.connect()` method.  LOG and handle all possible errors and your problem will become clear!  FYI, this is one of the basic rules of server code development.  Log and handle ALL possible errors.

Comment: Most likely, the root cause of the error that you are not paying attention to is that you're leaking some resource and eventually you run out (perhaps a DB connection).  If you log all errors, it will probably help you identify what type of resource you are having a problem with.

Comment: Thank you all for you suggestions and pointing me in the right direction. I was initiating a new connection every time to send data. I fixed it and now it seem to be working fine. Thank you very much.